# creating a list of textboxes in C#

Tags: c#, selenium

I just started learning C# and Selenium, I have a project on which am working, in this project I need to be able to create a function button so that when the user clicks it a text box appears, in which the user can place "text" or "numbers" they can remove and add them like a list. I don't have enough experience and knowledge on C# so I couldn't explain it better but a good way to understand what am building its like a application for shopping like when someone goes to buy grocery they place all that they might need to buy into a "list of text boxes". I have tried the following but I don't think this was the way or maybe I just didn't do it properly.`

```
private void plusbutton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            List<string> myOS = new List<string>();

        myOS.Add("windows1");
        myOS.Add("linux");
        myOS.Add("peter");
        myOS.Add("sasuke");
        foreach (string res in myOS)
            string textbox = textbox1.Text;`
```

EDITED; so what am working towards is creating a button that every time I click it it creates a textbox, imagine it like a `+` sign and every time you click it a textbox appears in which I can for example put `buy eggs` and if I need to buy something more I would just click `+` to create a new `textbox` and from each textbox's content would be sent to a webpage with selenium (send keys). hope this helped more!

Comment: This sounds like an [X-Y problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Instead of asking for help with your solution to the problem, edit your question and ask about the actual problem. What are you trying to do?

Comment: please let me know if this is better.

Comment: Selenium is best suited for _Browser Automation_ where as you seem to looking for _App Development_???

Comment: yeah i need to combine them so that when I click to add a text box whatever is inside gets sent to a webpage

Comment: You should probably remove the "Selenium" tag here since the code is all C#/.NET interface stuff.  What you need is a dynamic view.   So build an array of view items (in this case a textbox.. and anything associated with it, labels, etc...)  Then build a refresh function that updates the UI with the array of view items.  (You can also tie the view array with a data array...)  When you click add, you add a new view item (input box, labels, index, etc..) to the view array.  Then call your refresh function that updates the UI according to the arrays.

Answer (score 1):

if i understand you correctly you want to have a `Listbox` containing `Textboxes` as sort of a todo list. Although i think this is not the best way to do it, you could create a `ListBox.ItemTemplate` containing a `Textbox` and just use any `ObservableCollection` as a `Listbox.ItemsSource`. That way a new `Listbox.Item` gets created evertime you add a new Item to the `ObserableCollection` (you have to do that on the button click) Like this:

XAML:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="4*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Button Click="AddToListBoxClick" Grid.Row="0" Content="add Item" Width="200" Height="50"/>
    <ListBox Name="MyListbox" Grid.Row="1">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <TextBox Width="300" Height="30"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

C#:

```
// using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        MyListbox.ItemsSource = indexes;
    }

    ObservableCollection<int> indexes = new ObservableCollection<int>();
    
    void AddToListBoxClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        indexes.Add(indexes.Count);
    }
```